# git add sometimes doesnt work in bash script

Tags: git, bash

Alias another git question.
Where I work we have a rather unusual workflow so I've built a gui to manage commits

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /my/git/repo/
git add -u
git add -A
git commit -m $1
git pull
git push
git status
```

I then run this script by clicking a commit button on my webUI which simply runs this bash script with phps shell_exec and return git status output to the gui.

The problem is that sometimes (not often enough to pinpoint the issue) the script fails with the response that there are still unstaged files in the directory, and from there the tool is broken until a manual add/commit is done.

(will post a error message when I can reproduce a nice clean one)

using --force in the add does fix this but --force also ignores .gitignore, I'd like to fix it without using -f

Is there a way you force add the directory while still honouring .gitignore?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT: here is the error

```
[master e02cb4b] test 2 files changed, 6 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-) 
Already up-to-date. 
On branch master Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'. 
Changes not staged for commit: 
(use "git add ..." to update what will be committed) 
(use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory) 
modified: ANN/ANN3_1/ann-styles-varB.css no changes added to commit 
(use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: `--force` on which add? Why are you pulling before committing? Shouldn't that be the other way around? Are you at all concerned about merges needing to be done at any point in this process?

Comment: It seems unusual to me that you are pulling after you start adding your changes but before you commit.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: In regards to the workflow: no we are a a/b testing company and every piece of code in this repository runs in isolation there is only a single branch and there is some automation that cherry picks a folder and moves it to a production server.

This is not a common workflow, but it is the best for us because of the nature of the work version control would be a big road block using the normal git workflow options.

Comment: evinL I've been playing with where to do the pull, normally it would go after the commit* but it doesn't seem to make much difference. EtanReisner i can replace both add's with git add --force -A . and it's works 100% but it doesn't honour .gitignore - adding a pile of osx invisible junk files to the repository. I could fix this with a cron job to clean out the directory every few minutes but that seems like the wrong solution.


I've the pull back after the commit, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I agree that the pull should go after the commit -- otherwise you might mess up your working directory when you have merge conflicts.  Moreover, the `git add -u` seems redundant, since it does a subset of what `git add -A` does anyway.  Apart from that, I think you need to provide an error message for us to understand what's going wrong.

Comment: thanks for the responses so far i've put the pull back in the proper place and added the error message.

Comment: You appear to be sending a lot of commands to `git` without a single line of error checking. I would not recommend this strategy.

Comment: @abligh thanks for your advice, you may be right but could you be more specific with a recommendation.

Once again,we do not need to check the build merge/branch or unit test. Yes you would do this things in almost any other environment we are using git to manage logistics more so than version control.

Comment: In general in a shell script it is not wise to execute commands without checking for an error on the previous commands. Consider starting with `set -e` so the script aborts on an error.

Comment: That will stop the script from running in the gui and produce no useful output to the gui at least git status -v run with a 2&>1 produces a readable error message so the user can troubleshoot the issue without shell access.

at the very most I'd split the shell script up into several and output each step of the way. Thanks for the effort in the reply but I won't be doing that.

In the end the problem was solved, it was a hard drive issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments.

We discovered that the error was due to hardware constraints and was solved by mirroring the tool to a server with faster harddrives / raid array as a programmer could update a file between the commit and the push or the devboxs crappy hard drive could just be locked out.

So the solution was not in code but I did change the git add's to a single

```
git add -A .
```

Works flawlessly now.